# Remove an element in an Object Array in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document below:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'String',
  description: 'String',
  articles: [
    { reference: ObjectId, title: 'String', digest: 'String', content: '...' },
    { reference: ObjectId, title: 'String', digest: 'String', content: '...' },
    { reference: ObjectId, title: 'String', digest: 'String', content: '...' },
    { reference: ObjectId, title: 'String', digest: 'String', content: '...' },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to only remove one specific article with ObjectId `aid` from this document. So I use the method with `mongoose`:

```
Model.update({
  _id: 'the document ObjectId',
}, {
  $pull: {
    articles: {
      $elemMatch: {
        reference: aid,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

the result is:

```
{n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1}
```

But the document change is different from what I expect:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'String',
  description: 'String',
  articles: [],
}
```

I want to know why and how to remove one specific article as I expect.

Comment: You don't need to use `$elemMatch`  try this `$pull: {articles: {reference: aid}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Model.update({
    _id: 'the document ObjectId',
}, {
    $pull: {
        articles: { "reference" : aid}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$pull` operator for removing objects from the array in mongodb in the following way:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "the document ObjectId",{$pull: {arrayName: {"element Name": "element value"}}}})
```